# VSC breakpoints remain unbound

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use the Visual Studio Code debugger for debugging a Node.js application. However, all breakpoints remain "unbound". Why are the breakpoints not binding?

I use VSC v1.55.2 and Node v9.8.0.
My configuration `launch.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Server Side",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
            "request": "launch",
            "restart": true,
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "pwa-node",

            // I added:
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/",
            "trace": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

What have I tried but made no difference:

- I use `Use debug.javascript.usePreview: false` as recommended at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102166#issuecomment-657138385
- I added `localRoot` and `remoteRoot` as suggested in some posts.

Output upon Launch of the debugger:

```
cd "C:\\Users\\Xxx\\Documents\\vsc portal" ; /usr/bin/env '
NODE_OPTIONS=--require C:\Users\Xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-js-debug-bootlo
ader.js' 'VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS={"inspectorIpc":"\\\\.\\pipe\\node-cdp.7888-
2.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"C:\\Program Files
\\nodejs\\node.exe","onlyEntrypoint":false,"autoAttachMode":"always","fileCallb
ack":"C:\\Users\\Xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\node-debug-callback-4cee0248d1dfa
f08"}' "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\nodemon.cmd" .\\server.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55555/88f9181c-b2e1-4fe9-9df1-a20ba0485382
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node .\server.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55556/d9fd2280-08b7-4f4a-892d-f6562ec9441f
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55561/e504b1f9-67cf-41fc-89f7-cf3127f6850d
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

Verbose logs: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8x6nv9jvevcs74/vscode-debugadapter-b56a956a.json?dl=0

For example, I've added a break point on lines 3 and 5 of `server.js` that are both unbound:

```
const app = require("./app");
const { SERVER_PORT } = process.env;
app.set("port", SERVER_PORT);
const server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log(`Server running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: have you checked exactly where you are inserting breakpoints ? Seems VSC doesn't like breakpoints at -callbacks like the ones used by array.map/forEach etc. I have also seen this behaviour with async code but not always.

Comment: @ak_linus, I don't think that's it but to be sure I added an example of 2 break points at the end of the post to check. Shouldn't these break points work?

Comment: I tried the same settings on a new project and everything works as expected. I think there is something wrong with your node configuration, something outside VS Code. Have you tried to debug with `"runtimeExecutable": "node"` instead of `nodemon`

Comment: In the Debug window list, and under the general section, you can find the following option: 
'enable the debug JavaScript' or something like that, make sure it is selected, if it's selected then the problem is not in the visual studio debugger but with some other configuration.

Comment: I also did everything you did. That unbounded breakpoint errors drove me crazy. Try to clean rebuild your entire project.

Comment: I’ve tried `"runtimeExecutable": "node"` but unfortunately with the same result. 

I couldn’t find anything in settings on enabling/disabling JavaScript debugger. I did try “Allow setting breakpoints in any file” but that made no difference.

I’ve even set up a completely new workspace in VSC to see if that would help, but the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Node version 9.8.0, and updating to Node version 14.15.1 solved it.

Comment: That is not the solution in my case. I am on Node v. 16.14.2 and this unbound breakpoints issue just started occurring. I can't point to anything specific that changed. I'm trying to use use `node --inspect`.